# MaterialDatePicker.getHeaderText() returns 00 on month android

Tags: java, android, mobile, material-components-android, android-datepicker

[image: here is my code example]

i have a material date picker which i want to use to get a date my problem is when i try to format it to
**'yyyy-mm-dd'** it always **returns "00"** in months for example if a string **"Mar 5,2021"** the result will be **"2021-00-05"**
any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: Make sure you post your actual code in the question, not a picture.

Comment: sorry i thaught a screen snip would be nicer

Comment: No problem, if you could [edit] your post that would be great. Then people in the future can be helped by your question. Also you can take a look at [ask] to see how to ask a good question. There is a section about not posting images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` returns the selection as Long value. You don't need to get the HeaderText.

Use for example:

```
datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
    val utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    utc.timeInMillis = it
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val formatted: String = format.format(utc.time)        
}
```

Comment: yeah it works thank you sir, i cast the selection object to long and then formatted it as i wanted though "mm" must be upper case too